# Read only one record from Multiple text files into Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple txt files in a folder, which are tab delimited. Each of these files have a column called EngagementId, which is the same value, irrespective of number of records. However, it changes for every txt file, which is what I want to capture.

1. I am trying to get the file name in the first row. The GetFileNames() works for that (as pointed out in the comments)

---

```
Sub GetFileNames()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim splitFile As Variant

    'specify directory to use - must end in "\"
    sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    iRow = 0
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "\Individual Reports\")
    Do While sFile <> ""
        iRow = iRow + 1
        splitFile = Split(sFile, ".txt")
        For iCol = 0 To UBound(splitFile)
            Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol + 1) = splitFile(iCol)
        Next iCol
        sFile = Dir     ' Get next filename
    Loop
End Sub
```

Each of these txt files have one column (which is in the 13th position in each of the text files), called "EngagementId". I want to pull only the first "Engagement Id", which is from the 2nd row(since the first row contains headers).

```
Sub Extractrec()
    Dim filename As String, nextrow As Long, MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String, text As String, textline As String

    MyFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\Individual Reports\*.txt")

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, LineFromFile
            LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, "\t") 'second loop text is already stored 
                                                  '-> see reset text
            Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol + 2).Value = LineItems(13, 2)
        Loop
        Close #1

    Loop
```

Comment: What is the problem? I am not sure "\t" works in vba, I would use vbtab constant.

Comment: What are you showing us - do you have code that doesn't work the way you want it - what does it spit out now - and how should that change? Example data helps - are these two separate functions taht get called from somewhere else?

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol + 2).Value = LineItems(13, 2)` is going to be a Subscript out of range error - `Split` returns a one dimensional array.

Comment: @Comintern - and also because iRow will be zero (iCol is also zero, but iCol + 2 will evaluate to a valid column number)

Comment: @YowE3K - LOL! Missed that one. Your subscript error will throw before mine too.

Comment: The line saying `splitFile = Split(sFile, ".txt")` is weird - if someone creates a filename of "abcd.txtfile.txt.xls", you will end up with "abcd" in column A, "file" in column B, and ".xls" in column C

Comment: I need to pull only one data from each of the txt files. The first part of the script works, as I am pulling out file names, which is what I want to do. The second part is try to pull "EngagementId" from the 2nd row, from each of these text files, which I am unable to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need the second line of each file, you don't need to loop, just read and discard the fist line, then read and split the second one:

```
    Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1 'MyFolder & MyFile won't be the correct name (probably should be MyFolder & "\Individual Reports\" & MyFile)
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile 'line to discard
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile 'line to use
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, vbTab)
    Sheet1.Cells(someplace).Value = LineItems(13) ' replace some place with the correct value that we don't know
    Close #1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vincent. It works, but is there any way to quicken up the process? It hangs every time I try to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

Using an ADODB.Recordset to query would be more versatile.

---

```
Sub Example()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rs As Object, f As Object, conn  As Object
    Dim FolderPath As String, FileName As String, FilterString As String
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Sample Data File\"
    FileName = "example.csv"
    FilterString = "WHERE EngagementId = 20"

    Set rs = getDataset(FolderPath, FileName, FilterString)

    Do While Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("EngagementId")
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("Company")
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("City")
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("State")

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set conn = rs.ActiveConnection
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub

Function getDataset(FolderPath As String, FileName As String, FilterString As String) As Object
    Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    conn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FolderPath & ";" & _
             "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
    rs.ActiveConnection = conn
    rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM " & FileName & " " & FilterString
    rs.Open
    Set getDataset = rs
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. But I don't think this answers my question. I am a beginner in VBA coding. All I am trying to do is go thru multiple text files, in a folder and pull out the name of the file and one record , "EngagementId" from row 2 or any row, since all the values for EngagmentId for one text file is going to be the same. I have about 13 columns in my text file.